# Looping within a Looping creates duplicates in DataTable C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing to loop within a loop to write to a data table but it produces duplicates.  I'm not sure what the issue might here.  I"m getting duplicate ID's from this API as a result of this loop

```
var users = api.Users.GetAllUsers();

using (DataTable table = new DataTable())
{
   var properties = users.Users[0].GetType().GetProperties();

    for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count(); i++) 
    { 
        table.Columns.Add(properties[i].Name, typeof(String)); 
    }

   foreach (var user in users.Users)
   {
      DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
      for (int j = 0; j < properties.Count(); j++)
      {
            var colName = properties[j].Name;
            newRow[colName] = user.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(user, null);
      }
      table.Rows.Add(newRow);

      foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
      {
            Console.WriteLine(row["id"]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: No your are not getting duplicates. You need to move the loop that prints out the content of your table outside the loop the insert rows in your table. It is a trivial mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be just a display issue. You have a nested loop, you loop all rows in the table while you're adding new rows. That means you output all new rows. At the beginning you see only the one newly created row. But at the second user you're alreading seeing again the first row.

This fixes it, move the inner loop behind the main loop:

```
foreach (var user in users.Users)
{
    DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
    for (int j = 0; j < properties.Count(); j++)
    {
        var colName = properties[j].Name;
        newRow[colName] = user.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(user, null);
    }
    table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["id"]);
}
```

As an aside, you don't need to use the `using`-statement for a `DataTable` or `DataSet`.  It does not use unmanaged resources. The `using` will otherwise prevent you from further processing or returning it from the method. But this in an exception, in general it is best practice to use the `using`-statement for everything implementing IDisposable.

Comment: @FutureReaders Be careful not to think disposing does not matter,  `DataTable` is kind of a special case. It is only because DataTable implements the interface `IComponent` that it is disposable. If you are not using `IComponent.Site` or the `IComponent.Disposed` event on the data table (like how the OP is not) there is no need to dispose it.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a display problem. Your `foreach` and `Console.WriteLine` are inside the outer `foreach` so it's printing all rows on each iteration. Move the printing out of the outer `foreach`:

```
foreach (var user in users.Users)
{
   DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
   for (int j = 0; j < properties.Count(); j++)
   {
       var colName = properties[j].Name;
       newRow[colName] = user.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(user, null);
   }
   table.Rows.Add(newRow);
}

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine(row["id"]);
}
```